# Firebird cli import/export tool

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm looking for an import/export cli tool for firebird db that is comparable to mysql cli tools. Is fsql the best thing out there?

It needs to run on win,mac and linux.

Comment: what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: @hugues no worries. fsql is fine for what i need

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this: [FBExport/FBCopy](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/)